# Translate Sonata News bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, symfony-2.8

I need to translate my blog, build on Sonata News Bundle. I have sonata translation bundle, but it's not implemented inside News Bundle. Maybe someone has same issue? What is the way to translate it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[As described here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations), you can put your own translations of the bundle's translation strings in one of the two suggested locations in your application structure. They will take precedence over those provided by the bundle.

1. Take one of the [translation files provided by the bundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataNewsBundle/blob/2.x/Resources/translations/SonataNewsBundle.en.xliff)
2. Rename it and update the [source-language attribute](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataNewsBundle/blob/2.x/Resources/translations/SonataNewsBundle.en.xliff) to match the locale you are translating to
3. Translate the strings
4. Move it e.g. to `app/Resources/translations`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's not really what I need. I need to translate blog title, abstract and content fields, that comes from sonata admin.

Comment: @Stopper I see. Unfortunately I can't help with this issue.